Upsert on conflict primary key
I have this:
ON CONFLICT (cq_pk) DO UPDATE

SET

    count_1 = count_1_old

cq_pk is the name of a primary key. I keep getting an error message "cq_pk is not a column".
How do I do on conflict based on the name of a primary key instead of just a column list in case we ever change the primary key?

Reread the documentation for an insert statement, needed to do this:
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT cq_pk DO UPDATE

